# Let $α$ be an ordinal and $A$ be a set of ordinals. Then $\sup\limits_{β∈A} (α+β) = α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$

Tags: proof-explanation, ordinals

My idea is to prove that $\alpha+ \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is the supremum of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$. While I'm able to prove that $\alpha+ \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is a upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$, I failed to show that $\alpha+ \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)\le\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$.

The addition of ordinals is defined as follows $\alpha+0=\alpha$, $\alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1$, and $\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$ if $\beta$ is limit.

**My attempt:**

For all $\beta\in A,\beta\le\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$, then $\alpha+\beta\le\alpha+ \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ and thus $\alpha+ \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is a upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$. Assume that $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$, then $α+β\le\gamma$ for all $β∈A$.

**My questions:**

1. Please leave me some hints to complete my proof!
2. I meet another proof of this theorem on the Internet:

[image]

Could you please elaborate on the sentence *Since set inclusion is the ordering, the two are equal*. I'm unable to understand what this sentence means.

Thank you so much for your help!

---

> For an ordinal $α$ and a set $A$ of ordinals:
>
> - $\sup\limits_{β∈A} (α+β) = α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$
> - $\sup\limits_{β∈A} (α\cdot β)=α\cdot \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$

Comment: What is your definition of ordinal addition? The one by transfinite induction on the second argument?

Comment: Hi @GuillermoMosse! The addition is defined as follows $\alpha+0=\alpha$, $\alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1$, and $\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$ if $\beta$ is limit.

Comment: I don't know what you want to express with that yellow box. Is it another exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the $\leq$ inequality follows from the fact that $\forall \beta \in A, \alpha + \beta \leq \alpha + \sigma$, where $\sigma := \sup A$.

For the other inequality, you can argue as follows: if $\sigma \in A$, then the claim is trivial to prove, so assume that $\sigma \not\in A$. Then necessarily $\sigma$ is a limit ordinal, so $\sigma = \underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim} \eta$ (this doesn't happen if $\sigma$ is a succesor ordinal!).

By definition of ordinal addition, $\alpha + \sigma = \underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim} \alpha + \eta$. Convince yourself that you can exchange this expression with $\underset{\beta \in A}{\sup} \alpha + \beta$ using the definition of suprenum. So $\alpha + \sigma = \underset{\beta \in A}{\sup} \alpha + \beta$. But that is exactly what you want to prove.

As for the phrase *Since set inclusion is the ordering, the two are equal*, are you familiar with the basic definitions of ordinals as transitive and well ordered sets? The **definition** of $\alpha < \beta$  **is**  $\alpha \in \beta$. It follows from the construction of the ordinals that $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ is the same as $\alpha \leq \beta$.

A really nice book explaining the basic stuff is Introduction to Set Theory, by Hrbacek (page 107 in the third edition).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It seems to me that you meant $\alpha + \sigma = \alpha +  \underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim}\eta$ rather than $\underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim}\alpha+\eta$, and $ \alpha + \underset{\eta \in A}{\lim}\eta$ rather than $\underset{\eta \in A}{\lim} \alpha + \eta$. On the basis of your answer, I have presented a detailed proof and posted it as an answer below. If you don't mind, please have a look at it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank to your elaboration, I got what that sentence's meaning. But I think the author's proof is not sufficient and not complete. Although he has proved that all ordinals less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$ is also less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$, he has done NOTHING in proving the converse direction that all ordinals less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is also less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$. As a result, he can not claim that *Therefore the ordinals less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$ and the ordinals less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ are the same*. Thus he has not completed the proof.

Comment: @LeAnhDung, about the second comment, you are right! But the converse direction is easier, as you yourself noted. Maybe the author should have explicitely said that, anyway.

Comment: About the first comment, $\alpha + \sigma =\underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim}  \alpha + \eta$ by definition of ordinal addition for limit ordinals. (Of course, it is also equal to $\alpha + \underset{\eta < \sigma}{\lim} \eta$)

Comment: Honestly, I have not been able to prove the converse direction. I quite don't understand what you meant by *But the converse direction is easier, as you yourself noted*. Could you explain how to prove that all ordinals less than $α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$ is also less than $\sup\limits_{β∈A}(α+β)$?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85375/discussion-between-guillermo-mosse-and-le-anh-dung).

Comment: @GuillermoMosse By which property of supremum there exists $\eta$?

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of Guillermo Mosse's answer, I present a proof with detail here.

---

> **Lemma:** Let $B,C$ be sets, $B⊆C$ such that $∀c∈C,∃b∈B:c≤b$. Then $\sup B=\sup C$.

---

> $$\sup\limits_{β∈A} (α+β)=α+\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$$

Let $\sigma=\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. For all $\beta\in A,\beta\le\sigma$, then $\alpha+\beta\le\alpha+ \sigma$ and thus $\alpha+ \sigma$ is a upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$. Assume that $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $\{α+β\mid β∈A\}$, then $α+β\le\gamma$ for all $β∈A$.

1. If $\sigma\in A$ then $\sigma=\beta$ for some $\beta\in A$ and thus $\alpha+ \sigma=\alpha+ \beta\le\gamma$.
2. If $\sigma\notin A$ then clearly $\sigma$ is a limit ordinal. We next prove that $\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha+\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha+\eta)$.

Let $C=\{\alpha+\eta\mid \eta<\sigma\}$ and $B=\{\alpha+\eta\mid\eta\in A\}$. It's clear that $B\subseteq C$. For $\alpha+\eta\in C$, then $\eta<\sigma=\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. By property of supremum, there is $\eta'\in A$ such that $\eta<\eta'<\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. Thus $\alpha+\eta<\alpha+\eta'\in B$ for some $\eta'\in A$. Hence the conditions of **Lemma** are satisfied and thus $\sup B=\sup C$ or equivalently $\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha+\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha+\eta)$.

It follows that $\alpha+\sigma=\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha+\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha+\eta) \le\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\gamma)=\gamma$.

---

> $$\sup\limits_{β∈A} (α\cdot β)=α\cdot \sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$$

Let $\sigma=\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. We have $\forall\beta\in A:\beta\le\sigma$, then $\forall\beta\in A:\alpha\cdot\beta\le\alpha\cdot\sigma$ and thus $\alpha\cdot\sigma$ is an upper bound of $\{α\cdot β\mid β∈A\}$. Assume that $γ$ is an upper bound of $\{α\cdot β\mid β∈A\}$, then $\forall\beta\in A:α\cdot β\le\gamma$.

1. If $\sigma\in A$, then $\sigma=\beta$ for some $\beta\in A$ and thus $\alpha\cdot\sigma=\alpha\cdot\beta\le\gamma$.
2. If $\sigma\notin A$, then $\sigma$ is clearly a limit ordinal. We next prove that $\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha\cdot\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha\cdot\eta)$.

Let $C=\{\alpha\cdot\eta\mid \eta<\sigma\}$ and $B=\{\alpha\cdot\eta\mid\eta\in A\}$. It's clear that $B\subseteq C$. For  $\alpha\cdot\eta\in C$, then $\eta<\sigma=\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. By property of supremum, there is $\eta'\in A$ such that $\eta<\eta'<\sup\limits_{β∈A}(β)$. Thus $\alpha\cdot\eta<\alpha\cdot\eta'\in B$ for some $\eta'\in A$. Hence the conditions of **Lemma** are satisfied and thus $\sup B=\sup C$ or equivalently $\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha\cdot\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha\cdot\eta)$.

It follows that $\alpha\cdot\sigma=\sup\limits_{\eta<\sigma}(\alpha\cdot\eta)=\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\alpha\cdot\eta) \le\sup\limits_{\eta\in A}(\gamma)=\gamma$.

Comment: By which property of supremum there exists $\eta$?