# Let $\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}\beta_\nu$. How do the authors prove $\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)$?

Tags: proof-explanation, ordinals

Here is an excerpt from my textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech. Although I'm able to prove these three equalities, my proof is up to a page long containing even a lemma (If you are interested, you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2986616/368425)).

> [image]

I retype here.

> First we observe that the ordinal functions $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\cdot\beta$, and $\alpha^\beta$ are *continuous* in the second variable: If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}\beta_\nu$, then
>
> $$\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu), \alpha\cdot\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha\cdot\beta_\nu), \alpha^\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha^{\beta_\nu})$$
>
> This follows directly from Definitions 5.1, 5.6, and 5.9.

I add Definitions 5.1, 5.6, and 5.9 here for reference.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

I can not understand why the authors say **This follows directly...**. From my proof, I don't see it directly at all.

Could you please elaborate/explain what authors want to communicate by the sentence **This follows directly from Definitions 5.1, 5.6, and 5.9**?

Thank you so much for your help!

---

Comment: Hi @jgon! From definition, we have $\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$. To obtain $\alpha+\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)$, we must have $\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)=\sup\limits_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$. But i'm unable to prove $\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)=\sup\limits_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$ from $\beta=\sup\limits_{\nu<\gamma}\beta_\nu$. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I think it is clearer to define $\alpha+ \beta$ as the ordinal that is order-isomorphic to the lexicographic order on $(\{0\}\times \alpha)\cup (\{1\} \times  \beta),$ after showing that every well-order is order-isomorphic to  a unique ordinal. Further results  are then easily verified.

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet! I actually did what you have suggested. If you don't mind, please have a look at my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982516/the-sum-of-two-well-ordered-sets-is-isomorphic-to-the-sum-of-corresponding-ordin).