# Let $B,C$ be sets, $B\subseteq C$ such that $\forall c∈C,\exists b\in B: c\le b$ then $\sup B=\sup C$.

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, ordinals

I had been reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985740/let-%CE%B1-be-an-ordinal-and-a-be-a-set-of-ordinals-then-sup-limits-%CE%B2%E2%88%88a-%CE%B1%CE%B2). 
In the proof, below lemma is used. I don't know how to go for proving it.*Notice that I want to prove this theorem for set of ordinals not real numbers*

> Let $B,C$ be sets, $B\subseteq C$ such that $\forall c∈C,\exists b\in B: c\le b$.
>   Then $\sup B=\sup C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all $B\subseteq C$, so any upper bound of $C$ is an upper bound of $B$, hence $\sup C$ is an upper bound of $B$. Because $\sup B$ is the least upper bound of $B$ we conclude that $\sup B\leq\sup C$.

Now let any $c\in C$. There is an element $b\in B$ such that $c\leq b\leq \sup B$. Hence $\sup B$ is an upper bound of $C$. But $\sup C$ is the least upper bound of $C$, so we conclude $\sup C\leq\sup B$.

Comment: For the 2nd part,  $\forall c\in C\,\exists b\in B\,(c\leq b)$ implies that any upper bound of $B$ is an upper bound of $C$. Combined with the 1st part, we see that the set of upper bounds of $C$ is equal to the set of upper bounds of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

This holds generally in partially ordered sets.

> *Let $B\subseteq C$ be subsets of the partially ordered set $(X,\le)$. Suppose that, for every $c\in C$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $c\le b$. If one among $B$ and $C$ has the supremum, then both have and they are equal.*

Consider $B^*$ the set of upper bounds of $B$ and define similarly $C^*$. From $B\subseteq C$ it follows that $C^*\subseteq B^*$.

Let $x\in B^*$ and suppose $c\in C$. Then there is $b\in B$ such that $c\le b$. As $b\le x$, we have $c\le x$. Hence $x\in C^*$.

Therefore $B^*=C^*$ and the statement follows.

If $X$ is a set of ordinals, then every upper bounded subset of $X$ has the supremum (but a subset may not be upper bounded).